# text in the input field which cannot be deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've an input field such as

```
<input type="text" value="static text">
</input>
```

Is it possible that `static text` cannot be deleted or selected? This is required so that user can input text after the 'static text'.

Comment: Can't think if this is possible :D

Comment: <input type="text" value="Static text " /> Then the user can write someting after the static text, but it is still possible to delete.

Comment: You can use a left padding to input field and a background image with text of static content

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest you to do this way (*just HTML & CSS Solution*):

```
<label for='txt'>static text
   <input type="text" id='txt' value=""/>
</label>
```

Put your `input[type=text]` in a `label` and give some id as i given here as `#txt` and do some styling in the css as below:

```
#txt {
   border:none;
   outline:none;
}
label[for="txt"] {
   border:solid 1px #d5d5d5;
   padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

#### [A demo for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/z3mET/)

Answer (score 7):

You can use two `input` tags(with one disabled, to act as the "static" text) wrapped inside a `div`, something like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="static" value="fixed" disabled>
    <input type="text" id="user">
</div>
```

(you can also use the `readonly` attribute instead of the `disabled` attribute)

and then you can style the tags so that they look/behave the way you want.

```
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:inline-block
}
#static {
    width:30px;
    background: white; // not required if you 
    color: black;      //   use readonly
}
input {
    border: none;
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/s4whY/1/)

Edit: Use Javascript to prevent the user from selecting the static text:

```
document.getElementById('static').onselect = function (event) {
    event.target.selectionStart = event.target.selectionEnd;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/s4whY/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Mind is kinda the same as Jai, i just uses a span istead of a label, just personal prefferences.

```
<span class="static_text">Static text </span>
<input type="text" placeholder="your text here..." />
```

and then just style it to make it look like one box:

```
input {
    display: block;
    margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-left: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 18px;
}

.static_text {
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-right: none;
    float: left;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g7f7R/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should use two input box,make one disable and remain other editable and apply css according to requiement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's keydown event to allow the users to type additional text in the textbox but prevent them to delete the fixed text. Below is an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function ValidateInput(ctrl) {
            if (event.keyCode == 8 ||event.keyCode == 46) {   //backspace pressed or delete key pressed
                //check whether the user is trying to delete the fixed text
                if (ctrl.selectionStart <= 4) return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value="1234" onkeydown="return ValidateInput(this);"/>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also convert the above logic using jquery which will be more simpler and readable.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqqbp9bx/)

```
#txt {
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
label[for="txt"] {
    border:solid 1px #d5d5d5;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A message several years later... For my part, I have a field named "source" on my page.
I get the number of characters (XX.value.length) and I compare if this value is less or equal to selectionStart.
If the person places his cursor on the element not to be deleted, I cancel the action.
In the example, if the person puts his cursor between 1 & 2, he can't delete.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function ValidateInput(ctrl) {
                var value = document.getElementById("Source").value;
            
            if (event.keyCode!= 37 && event.keyCode != 39) {
                if (ctrl.selectionStart < value.length) return false;
            }
            
            if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46) {
                if (ctrl.selectionStart <= value.length) return false;
            }
            
            return true;
            
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value="1234" onkeydown="return ValidateInput(this);"/>
    <input type="text" id="Source" name="Source" value="1234" disabled/>
</body>
</html>
```