# How to disable certain string inside text box?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, textbox

What I done as code below show that all the data inside text-box was disable.

```
Private Sub chkSTC_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkSTC.CheckedChanged
        Select Case chkSTC.Checked
            Case True
                txtCargoDescription.Enabled = False
               
            Case False
                txtCargoDescription.Enabled = True
               
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

How to disable only certain string which is `"1 X 40 HQ STC"` from text-box. What should I add?

Please refer this image:

[image: Please refer this image]

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Seems this solution fits what you want in client-side: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21982192. You can refer to `keydown` or `keypress` event in textarea then use `event.keyCode` to find out if backspace/delete button pressed in keyboard.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto tq and i will try

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can only disable controls. You can't disable a string within a control. The best you could do is write event handlers (e.g. OnChange) that cancel the event if it would result in the string being modified. A more common solution though would be to put the string in a separate control.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable a string inside a textbox but you can prevent user from making change within that string. For example, if a user tries to add a character, remove or do any change inside that string, don't let them happen.

I did this:

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    'see if any change is made between the first 13 characters (13 characters because "1 X 40 HQ STC" had 13 chars)
    If sender.selectionstart <= 14 Then

        'see if a character is deleted (tried to press backspace or delete key)
        If e.KeyCode = 8 Or e.KeyCode = 46 Then
            'replace the first 12 characters with our orignal text
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 12), "1 X 40 HQ STC")
            'if left or right key is pressed
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
            'do nothing
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 15), "1 X 40 HQ STC")
        Else
            'it means other text is added, remove 14 characters and put our original string
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 14), "1 X 40 HQ STC")
        End If
        'set the cursor to 15th character, i.e. next line
        sender.selectionstart = 15

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: HI Subaz, can u please show it from my code above? because `"1 X 40 HQ STC"` retrieve from db.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Write data validation procedure to remove "1 X 40 HQ STC", so that only wanted strings can be displayed.